# r hist function to calculate probability/density not based on break width

Tags: r, histogram

the hist() function in R calculates probability/density based on the width of the breaks if freq=FALSE, example here [density/frequency and probability in hist()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32564005/density-frequency-and-probability-in-hist) 
But I would simply like to have and plot the **relative frequency**, probability within each break based on the total number of elements in the vector, not considering the width because I have breaks with various lengths. Is there a simple way to achieve this or do I have to do it manually?
Example

```
v=seq(1,10,1)
h=hist(v,breaks = c(1,8,10))
$breaks
[1]  1  8 10

$counts
[1] 8 2

$density
[1] 0.1142857 0.1000000
```

I would like to get .8 and .2 for the first and second breaks, and then I would like to plot a histogram using these values.

Comment: An example of what you're looking for would be helpful

Comment: @RichardBorder fixed

Comment: `h$counts/length(v)` [1] 0.8 0.2

Comment: @42- thank you that is easy but I would like to plot those values instead of the densities provided by hist(), doesn't hist have any option to do this or should I use ggplot?

Comment: `barplot` (usually based on a `table` operation) would be the base plotting solution. The R-core is rather protective toward the `hist` function. They don't like it being corrupted by non-histogramish notions.

Comment: @42- I guess they look at the very strict meaning of histogram